# VMWare ESX 4 Metrics

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere

Recently joined a new company and the production ESX farm doesn't keep any performance metrics  does anyone know of a way to solve this?

If I view realtime metrics it works but if i change to Day/Month/All time it doesn't show any data

I will try to post more information tomorrow once back at work if needed.

Comment: What version of vCenter?

Comment: As far as i remember it is vCenter 4 as its the whole vSphere package ill check tomorrow and give you more information :)

Comment: SQL Express or full version of SQL?

Comment: Full version of SQL server

Comment: Run exec sp_who on the SQL server to see if there is connectivity between the database server and vCenter? You should see open connections from the vCenter SQL user on the vCenter database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to VMware the issue is due to a corrupt template that we use to build machines.

If we build a new VM it is working fine and we have been advised to recreate our template machine

Answer (score 0):

You have to be using vCenter for this.  Using the Infrastructure Client connect to the vCenter server.  In the menus, select "Administration" then "VirtualCenter Management Server Configuration...".  There need to be check marks next to the Interval Durations.

Comment: Yeah im aware of that already i have been talking to VMware devs about the issue and they believe it may be due to the original template that we use to deploy virtual servers and have requested that we try to create a new one.

Comment: That sucks.  Do you have the VMware Tools up to date?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you need to increase the level of the statistics that vCenter is collecting. Doing so will dramatically increase the size of your vCenter database, but will give you access to a larger set of tracked values.

Read the administration guides for vSphere ([4.1, chapter 9](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere4/r41/vsp_41_dc_admin_guide.pdf) and [4.0, chapter 22](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere4/r40_u1/vsp_40_u1_admin_guide.pdf)). These will show you how to increase the logging levels, and what stats get kept at each level.

Once you increase the levels, you'll need to wait until the statistics roll up jobs get run before the additional counters are made available in the vCenter performance tab. Given that, don't worry if it takes 24 hours before you get the ability to select them.